# Доступ к Gii в Yii2 с ЧПУ

Tags: yii2

До включения ЧПУ генератор доступ по адресу

> hostname/index.php?r=gii

После того как ЧПУ активирован hostname/gii не работает
Для него может rule надо прописать своё? Но как? Варианты

> 'gii' => 'gii', и 'gii' => 'gii/index',

не заработали

Comment: что в конфиге прописано покажи........ `index.php` из урла убирал? по идее после нормальных конфигов должно работать `hostname/gii`....... попробуй еще `hostname/web/gii`

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский hostname/web/gii пробовал не работает, отключил ЧПУ на время но удивился что страница с gii всё так же отдаёт в ответ ошибку 403, хотя остальные страницы работают

Comment: еще раз напишу: покажи конфиг....... + htaccess

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский а он меня из-за ip наверное не пускает...

Comment: Код конфига с Gii и ЧПУ https://pastebin.com/Q6yeuEPA

Comment: C такими настройками должен работать `hostname/web/gii` ... либо в htaccess что-то прописано, либо что-то ты недосказал)) например причем тут ip)) если ты пытаешься с удаленного компа подключиться, то надо `'allowedIPs'` еще в настройки. причем **НЕ** 127.0.0.1